# Every shutdown takes very long. Issue: "A stop job is running for session c2 of user xxx"

Tags: release-hera, shutdown

I have just installed elementary Hera. 
But I have one problem every time I shutdown my PC I get the following message:

~a stop job is running for session c2 of user xxx~

Then the 90 seconds timer counts down and I have to wait.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May you try looking at this other answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273876/a-stop-job-is-running-for-session-c2-of-user? I feel your issue is not directly related to elementary, so you can find useful help in other resources.

Comment: I researched a bit and found this: https://gist.github.com/dianjuar/98d02af4050dc2df8ae6f18695d44ca3 but I'm unsure whether this is a real solution... :-/

Comment: Have you tried looking at the logs after a shutdown? Journalctl persist logs from previous boot sessions. Follow the steps described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496563/111295 Maybe you will find something helpful?

Comment: Ok I have tried this Journalctl thing. The following processes were killed: the last three times: ~session-c2.scope: Killing process 4989 (io.elementary.c) with signal SIGKILL.~ one time: ~cups-browsed.service: Killing process 879 (cups-browsed) with signal SIGKILL.~

Comment: I've been able to find this issue https://github.com/elementary/cerbere/issues/35 Can you confirm cerbere is the problem here? I suspect the "io.elementary.c" is missing a piece and should be "cerbere" instead. If that is the case, you should probably ask in the GitHub issue to help troubleshoot and solve it.

Comment: I have recheck this and I can confirm I just copy pasted the complete line after searching for "timed out. Killing" And it is exactly: "session-c2.scope: Killing process xxxx (io.elementary.c) with signal SIGKILL." There was no "cerbere" written. I have no searched through the complete "journalctl". One time: "cups-browsed.service: Killing process 879 (cups-browsed) with signal SIGKILL." and 18 times io.elementary.c. Only the process no. is everytime different. (process numbers: 4989; 5172; 4120; 12745; 4525; 4185; 4989; 9423; 12712; 10288; 7109; 11150; 4213; 4894; 9030; 24750; 11536; 21682)

Comment: Oh I have looked in the github link, on the screenshots they also have this "io.elementary.c" inside, so I assume that this could be the same thing. Thank you for this hint!

Comment: Nice to know! Happy to convert the comment in the accepted answer, or do it yourself and accept the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and could not find a solution, you can set the timer to a smaller value in: `/etc/systemd/system.conf`. (If it is empty, here is a copy: https://p.ip.fi/bZfs)

Uncomment line `DefaultTimeoutStopSec=90s` then change it to a lower value.
Then run `systemctl daemon-reload`

Hope it helps...

Comment: I also have this issue, and managed to identify cerbere as the culprit. Still, no idea how to fix it. What's worse is that it does not happen all the time.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But reducing the timeout is the last chance if I don't find any other solution to fix this.

Comment: Yes, for me also is cerbere, sometimes it is Gala (?!?) and no idea how to fix it.. So my 'solution' is also to reduce the timeout time.

Comment: I have tried to edit /etc/systemd/system.conf. But the file is empty?!?

Answer (score 0):

See comments from [endorama](/questions/tagged/endorama): This problem is an open issue on github -->  [github.com/elementary/cerbere/issues/35](http://%20github.com/elementary/cerbere/issues/35)

Comment: PS: is perfectly acceptable to answer your own questions! Feel free to flag this as the accepted answer to aid future readers.

Comment: The problem was fixed for some month and since updates from yesterday (29.05.2020) I have again this "a stop job is running for session c2 of user xxx" message and have to wait 90 seconds. The liked github archive was closed...